# Java API vs Frameworks?

Tags: java, api, collections, frameworks

What would be the difference between the Collections Framework and Collections API? I have heard that "API is a subset of a framework". Wouldn't it be the other way around since a framework provides a more specific function, while an interface is more broad and abstract? I've also heard that a framework can contain multiple APIs. Does that mean that also frameworks are custom made?

Comment: The I in API stands for Interface. A Framework includes implementation. An API could as well be implemented by more than one framework.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772746/difference-between-framework-vs-library-vs-ide-vs-api-vs-sdk-vs-toolkits post might help.
It is very neatly explained.

Comment: already seen that post. still not clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Framework Vs. API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724380/framework-vs-api)

Comment: "Collections Framework and Collections API" There is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, what is the definition of **API**? According to Beal (n.d.), the API "is a set of routines, protocols, and tools for building software applications. The API specifies how software components should interact and APIs are used when programming graphical user interface (GUI) components."

Secondly, what is a **framework**? According to Rouse (205), "a framework is often a layered structure indicating what kind of programs can or should be built and how they would interrelate."

So, the framework **dictates what kind of programs can or should be built**. Meanwhile, an API **specifies how software components should interact**. From the definitions, it could be told that the framework is the **skeleton** of the program, while the API is the **organ system** of the program. Additionally, a framework consists of multiple APIs. For instance, the Microsoft .NET Framework, it provides several APIs such as the System.IO, System.Data, etc.

References

Beal, V. (n.d.). API - Application program interface. Webopedia. Retrieved 07-17-2015 from http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/API.html.

Rouse, M. (2015, February). Framework. WhatIs. Retrieved 07-17-2015 from http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/framework.

Comment: bad answer. use your own words